why can't I access rtsp camera in python?
I'm trying to access an RTSP camera in Python and get frame information from it.
One of the camera options is RTSP authentication, and when I include it, VLC asks for login information. ('[rtsp @ ] method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized')
If I turn it off, I can access it regardless of ID or PW, but if I turn it on, I can't access it from Python.
I verified that it works by putting the same RTSP address, ID, and PW in VLC, and it doesn't contain any symbols like '@' which is a common problem.
I used several libraries, including Opencv, ffmpeg, and others, and got the same
'[rtsp @ ] method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized' and only this error appears
What could be the cause,,, please help...
import cv2

url = "rtsp://username:password@camera_ip:554/stream_path"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open RTSP stream.")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Failed to read frame.")
        break
    cv2.imshow('RTSP Stream', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I tried running the above code and debugging it using the ffmpeg library.

Which camera ? Should work with the code. Opencv use ffmpeg i think so which Other did you try?

You are using a TIC-A2336 RPZ.
Currently, when I removed the RTSP authentication option (login), I found that I can access via Python.
I checked FFMPEG of course, and GStreamer doesn't work (but Nvidia's Deepstream works, so I don't know why).

Then you should debug with wireshark

Sorry, I don't know how to analyze wireshark, can you tell me what to focus on?

On the rtsp authentication ;) time to learn hehe

I haven't checked Wireshark, but I have a hunch.
There are two types of RTSP authentication, basic authentication and digest authentication, and I don't think Python (or OpenCV) can get digest authentication.
But for that camera, it only supports digest authentication.
So it's not possible?

All the tools should Work with basic or digest ;)

Yesterday, I saw the following on another device that supports two authentication methods (basic, digest).
By keeping the same RTSP address, username, and password, and only changing the camera authentication option, I was able to access Basic, but not Digest.

I use all the tools with basic or digest for diffrent vendors like Axis, Sony, Bosch, Hikvision... maybe the camera vendor fucked up digest authentication.
